# Test datetime fields as a JSON string using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to test a JSON response with rspec (in Rails) by equality between `[the original object].to_json` and the response body. The problem is that the `updated_at` and `created_at` fields in the response JSON string are different than the same fields in the original object by milliseconds and therefore the test failed.

The test:

```
lesson = FactoryGirl.create(:lesson)
request.accept = "application/json"
get :show, {:id => lesson.to_param, :location_id => lesson.location_id}, valid_session
response.body.should eq lesson.to_json
```

The result:

```
expected: "{\"id\":1,\"location_id\":1,\"day_number\":5,\"time\":\"17:00\",\"min_age\":4,\"max_age\":10,\"created_at\":\"2013-10-02T00:51:53.870+03:00\",\"updated_at\":\"2013-10-02T00:51:53.870+03:00\"}"
        got: "{\"id\":1,\"location_id\":1,\"day_number\":5,\"time\":\"17:00\",\"min_age\":4,\"max_age\":10,\"created_at\":\"2013-10-02T00:51:53.000+03:00\",\"updated_at\":\"2013-10-02T00:51:53.000+03:00\"}"
```

Note that the two strings are equal, except the 870 milliseconds in the expectation (and 000 in the actual result).

How can I test that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would parse JSON response `JSON.parse(response.body)` and verified that:

1) `lesson.attributes.keys` contains exactly the same keys as in the parsed JSON;

2) checked that each value except `created_at` and `updated_at` matches to the appropriate key value from the parsed JSON.

3) If you want you can test `created_at` and `updated_at` for presence as well.

Comment: This is definetely reasonable workaround for this specific case but it doesn't solve the problem of matching `created_at` and `updated_at`

Answer (score 4):

I've accomplished this in a better way by comparing the datetime from the json response to my object's `datetime_field.as_json`:

```
expect(json_body).to eq {
  order: {
    ordered_at: order.ordered_at.as_json 

    # ... other fields
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this way is much better:

```
JSON.parse(response.body).except('created_at', 'updated_at').should eq lesson.attributes.except('created_at', 'updated_at')
```

Comment: I think a better alternative would be: expect(last_response.body).to eq lesson.attributes.to_json

Answer (score 0):

I think you're seeing two different values because the data in those objects is coming from two different places: Ruby, and your database, and the database stores timestamps at a lower precision than Ruby produces them.

Quick fix: reload your in-memory record before comparing them, `lesson.reload` on line 2. This will discard the extra precision the model instance returned by the factory is holding in its ruby generated Time objects.

```
lesson = FactoryGirl.create(:lesson)
lesson.reload
request.accept = "application/json"
get :show, {:id => lesson.to_param, :location_id => lesson.location_id}, valid_session
response.body.should eq lesson.to_json
```

Why: The created_at and updated_at timestamp values are (normally) produced by Rails, in Ruby, with `Time#now` or similar. When they're stored in the database, it'll truncate the value to fit its data type. When you load it back into Ruby, it'll use the information it's given, and fill the rest with zeroes, similar to setting the time to midnight when you only give it a date.

Alternatively, if you don't want to hit the database (slow tests, but in this case I'd go simplicity over speed) you could truncate the time values on the object your factory returns, bringing them into line with the precision you get from the database.

A different issue (that this was the only result for) is comparing `Rails#to_formatted_s(:iso8601)` against the API results and seeing more or fewer trailing zeroes in the expected or returned value. Look at using `Time#iso8601` in your test instead, it has a fraction-digits argument that Rails doesn't.